# He is not even fluent in his mother tongue. OR He is even poor at speaking his mother tongue

Tags: north-american-english

He is not even fluent in his mother tongue. 
OR 
He is even poor at speaking his mother tongue.

Which one is correct? If I wrong, What would the correct sentence be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is better. 
The second one should instead be "He is poor at even speaking his mother tongue".
But it still sounds a little unnatural.

Comment: I would suggest the otherwise. As I would explain things with a grammatically positive but negative in meaning sentence.